# Construct compact subset of a set

Tags: real-analysis, compactness

In the context of uniform continuity in our analysis course we often need compact sets or compact subsets to prove certain properties. I am not sure if I have fully understood how to construct a compact subset and why we are allowed to do this. May be someone can give me an explanation to the following issue.

Let's assume that $M\subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is an open set, with $M\neq\emptyset$ . As $M$ is open there exists a neighbourhood for an arbitrary point $m\in M$: $U_{\delta}(m):= \{x\in M~|~\Vert x-m\Vert<\delta\}\subset M$, where $\delta >0$. Now, I simply take a $\delta_0$ with $0<\delta_0<\delta$ and define a compact subset by $C:=\{x\in M~|~\Vert x-m\Vert\leq\delta_0\}\subset M$. Is this correct?

Is it possible to construct a compact subset in this way when we don't have furhter information on $M$ (open, not-open, closed, not-closed)?

Comment: If you're working in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $C$ is compact. In metric spaces, if you start with a compact subset $C$, then any closed subset of it $D\subseteq C$ will also be compact. So compact sets can be very complicated.

Comment: The set $M$ is an open set *where*? Is it an open subset of $\Bbb R^n$?

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Yes, it should be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$. I have edited the question.

Comment: Are you only using usual topology here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $M$, yes, what you did is correct: the set $C$ that you have difined is compact.

If there is no assumption about $M$, then it may well happen that the only compact subsets of $M$ are the finite ones (note that every finite subset of $\Bbb R^n$ is compact). That's the case is, for instance, $M=\Bbb Q^n$.